# Obsolete Material

Tags: destiny

Are

- "Hadronic Essence"
- "Plasteel Plating"
- "Sapphire Wire"

now total obsolete so I can trade all of them for "Armor Materials", without regretting it in a while?

Are there any other materials that are totally obsolete?

I'm just asking this because I'm a day one player that hasn't played Destiny (vanilla) for a while now and bought the Legendary Edition and now my material-inventory is full.

Comment: About to be in this same situation.... sold original and picked up the new version and so will be returning to the game, good to know!

Comment: This is not the question you asked, but just as a tip: I would suggest using them for faction rep instead of exchanging them for armor materials. Weapon/armor upgrades are much less expensive now, you don't need 25 materials/armor mats/weapon parts, just 5 or 10.  I never converted any of my old mats to the newer armor materials and so far have not run out at all when upgrading my new gear. YMMV of course.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

They can be exchanged for reputation with one of the tower factions (New Monarchy, Dead Orbit, or Future War Cult), or exchanged at a 1:1 ratio for new armor materials in the tower. All armor (new and old) has been switched over to the new singular currency, so there are no drawbacks to switching them over.

Comment: Could you be more specific about where to exchange for Armor Materials? I don't recall seeing such an option anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they should be AFAIK

A quick peek through my vault at older Year 1 armour that I never fully upgraded but don't want to dismantle shows that the remaining upgrade slots now want Armor Material instead of the class-specific armour materials.